# Getting "The name 'SomeName' does not exist in the current context" when extending ContentView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

First, I have an abstract class called `ComponentView` inheriting from `ContentView`:

```
public abstract class ComponentView : ContentView
{
    private ComponentView() {}

    protected ComponentView(Component component)
    {

    }
}
```

The above class is extended by some custom visual components. I started by creating a component called `SeparatorView`. The XAML structure and the C Sharp code behind code is as follows:

Code behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SeparatorView : ComponentView
{
    private readonly Separator _separator;

    public SeparatorView(Separator separator) : base(separator)
    {
        _separator = separator ?? throw new ArgumentException("Separator cannot be null");

        InitializeComponent();
        RootComponent.AutomationId = _separator.Id;
        Label.Text = _separator.Label;
        HelpBlock.Text = _separator.HelpBlock;
    }
}
```

XAML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:ComponentView x:Name="RootComponent" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="clr-namespace:CustomViews.Components"
             x:Class="CustomViews.Components.SeparatorView">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="Label"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Label x:Name="HelpBlock"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
</d:ComponentView>
```

When I try to use this custom `SeparatorView` I'm getting this error at compiling time:

```
var separator = new Separator
{
    Id = "id",
    Label = "Separator",
    HelpBlock = "Help block"
};
var separatorView = new SeparatorView(separator);
StackLayout.Children.Add(separatorView);
```

> **SeparatorView.xaml.cs(17, 13):** [CS0103] The name 'RootComponent' does
>   not exist in the current context

When I remove the line:

```
RootComponent.AutomationId = _separator.Id;
```

the code works and my component is correctly rendered.

Am I forgetting something? Is this related to my class structure?

Comment: Are you sure you can name the root element? Shouldn't you just be using `this.AutomationId = _separator.Id;`?

Comment: Hi @DavidG, I'm not sure whether I can name the root element, but seems that you are right! Changing my code to `AutomationId = _separator.Id;` works. But now is not clear for me **why** I cannot reference the root element by name in the code behind. Have you any hint?

Comment: XAML is designed to give you elements that sit *inside* the root. Why should you name it when it's always going to be `this`?

Comment: @DavidG make sense. Can you answer my question with your considerations? This way I can accept it as the right solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't name the root element. In fact, there's no need to because that element is the class you are already inside, it's effectively `this`. So instead of:

```
RootComponent.AutomationId = _separator.Id;
```

Just do this:

```
this.AutomationId = _separator.Id;?
```